# Symfony 5 Invalid argument supplied for foreach Doctrine CachedReader.php (method getDoctrine->getRepository)

Tags: symfony, foreach, doctrine

друзья. Возникла проблема, которую не могу решить. Делая по документации Symfony 5, выбрасывается исключение: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Stack Trace указывает на **vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/CachedReader.php:107**. И по сути мне не позволяет обращаться к репозиторию в контроллере. Сброс всего кэша Symfony помогает на один запрос, далее опять Exception повторяется. Пробовал изменять доступы директории с кэшем, не помогло. Буду рад решению.

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AuthorRepository::class)
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class AuthorRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Author::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class AuthorController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/author/create", name="author-create")
     * Method ({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function actionCreate(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator): Response
    {
        // throw ErrorException !!!
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Author::class);
    }
  
    // ...
 }
```

[image: method show Exception]

[image: Stack Trace]

[image: where the exception is thrown]

Answer (score 1):

Это были настройки доступа внутри контейнера. Этот пост помог разобраться:
[Folder permissions when running Symfony in Docker environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636596/folder-permissions-when-running-symfony-in-docker-environment)

**Dockerfile:**

```
&& usermod -u 1000 www-data
```